# How is it possible to declare a class (not an abstract one) and only write methods signature without any implementation

Tags: java, android, implementation

I know it isn't possible in Java. But in Android i see a lot of  library classes that have many method that have only signature without a body (missing implementation). 
For example: Applicatin.java -> method:  void onActivityCreated(@NonNull Activity activity, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState);

Comment: do you mean an Interface or an Abstract class? Both are possible in java by the way

Comment: You state that it isn't possible. But still you ask for a solution. Huh?

Comment: I am talking about a classes that aren't abstract!!!!

Comment: If you have a clear example, edit your question to include it. We ain't going to try to find where `Application.java` comes from. For all I know it could be an Interface file. There are formating tools to add code in the question, don't do it in a comment. I haven't donwvote this question yet, but don't complain you get downvote while you cant provide a proper example. You have 18 questions, you know how it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In java you can use an `interface` or an `abstract class`.

By providing a proper example, you would have figured out that the method `void onActivityCreated(@NonNull Activity activity, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState);` is not a method of the class `android.app.Application`.

Actually, it's a method of the `interface ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` which is defined inside the class `android.app.Application`, it's an inner interface.

Source: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/master/core/java/android/app/Application.java

```
public class Application extends ContextWrapper implements ComponentCallbacks2 {
    ...
    public interface ActivityLifecycleCallbacks {
        /**
         * Called when the Activity calls {@link Activity#onCreate super.onCreate()}.
         */
        void onActivityCreated(@NonNull Activity activity, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState);

        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use interfaces for that purpose implementation can be provided when u implement it or you can use abstract class

Comment: But the example shows a class, and not an abstract one. This is the class declaration: public class Application extends ContextWrapper implements ComponentCallbacks2 
 This is the issue! Did you set minus 1?

Comment: Please tell me if you read my question until the end.. I gave there a specific example of a class that i-s n-o-t an abstract and although you are writing me about abstract class as an answer to my question

Comment: Giving a java file name is not a `specific example of a class`